# A fat, soft teat people cling to their entire life

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> A fat, **soft teat people** cling to their entire life

This quote is from *WestWorld* Season 1 Episode 5.

What does **soft teat people** mean?

Comment: Imagine the word _which_ before _people_. Do you understand it now?

Comment: Nope , to be honest

Comment: Something is being described as 'a fat, soft teat' which, the speaker says, 'people cling to (for comfort) [for] their entire life'.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

A “teat” refers to a non-human mammary. In humans, we usually refer to a “breast”.

There is an expression about babies “clinging to their mother’s breast”, which refers to how babies naturally cling to their mothers for the nourishment and comfort.

Referring to humans clinging to a “teat” is a metaphor describing dependency on something non-human. “Fat” and “soft” implies ample nourishment and comfort is available enabling that dependency.

“cling to their entire lives” refers to how, contrary to our expectations for the young to eventually separate from their mothers and learn to provide for themselves, these people have never grown up and remain dependent.

Comment: Teats can be human.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I’ve never seen it used in a context that wasn’t dehumanizing to the woman.

Answer (score 2):

You have parsed the sentence incorrectly - there is no phrase "soft teat people" involved. Instead, it breaks down like this:

- "A teat"

  - qualified with the adjectives "fat, soft"
- [which] "people cling to"
- [for] "their entire life"

As [StephenS points out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/261453/9488), "teat" here is referring to a mother's breast, and the metaphor is that people are continuing to feed from it rather than growing up and becoming independent. The "fat, soft" is just reinforcing the imagery of the breast as plentiful and comforting.